# Obtain user and kernel time of a running process?

Tags: process, time

Is there way to determine using standard Linux/Unix tools how much a process has spent in User mode and how much waiting for kernel?

In other words, exactly the "user" and "sys" values that you get when using `time`, but **during** process runtime?

**NOTE:** one way is to use WBEM and enumerate Linux_UnixProcess, but I need to use *other* tool than this; my aim is to verify what WBEM provider tells me, i.e. I need to use different tool.

Comment: See `times(2)` and the `times` builtin of your shell. The `time` keyword of some shells when by itself also display the times.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas unfortunately i need to read the times per process, while and these calls give cumulative times from the shell and children.

Comment: No `times` give both the process' time and its (dead and waited for) children's time.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On Linux, the info is available in fields 14 to 17 of `/proc/$pid/stat` (see [proc(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) for details):

Fields are:

- 14: user time (in number of clock ticks)
- 15: sys time
- 16: user time of waited for children
- 17: sys time of waited for children

(all the threads of a given process have the same values there)

They are not directly reported by `ps`.

`ps` reports 14 + 15 with `ps -o time` and `14 + 15 + 16 + 17` with `ps --cumulative -o bsdtime`.

Beware that the second field in `/proc/$pid/stat` may contain spaces or newline characters, so you can't parse it with awk's `$1`, `$2`...

You can use `perl` like:

```
$ perl -MPOSIX -l -0777 -ne '@f = /\(.*\)|\S+/gs;
    printf "utime: %.2f\nstime: %.2f\ncutime: %.2f\ncstime: %.2f\n",
      map {$_/POSIX::sysconf( &POSIX::_SC_CLK_TCK )}@f[13..16]' "/proc/$pid/stat"
utime: 3.79
stime: 2.06
cutime: 56.49
cstime: 34.27
```

A process can retrieve its own times with `getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF)` and `getrusage(RUSAGE_CHILDREN)`.

There's also a `times` system call that retrieves the same information. POSIX shells have a `times` builtin for that. Some shells also provide with that information with `time` (without arguments).

```
$ times
0m3.800s 0m2.060s
0m56.512s 0m34.276s

$ ps -o time -p "$$"
    TIME
00:00:05
$ ps --cumulative -o bsdtime -p "$$"
  TIME
  1:36
```

Comment: Bash `times` A) does not allow me to see separate times for each child and B) seems to report times only from already terminated children.  I solved A by wrapping each child with a bash script that calls child and then only reports times, but still; due to B, there is necessary gap at best: 1. measure by WBEM, 2. kill, 3. read report.

Comment: tWhat about retrieving the user/system times for a thread? That's a problem I currently need solved (without passing RUSAGE_THREAD - which is Linux specific) to getrusage.